# Apache2 Setup Virtual Hosts with Subdomains using Django Projects

Tags: django, apache2, virtualhost

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu Server 12.04.  I'm trying to host multiple websites on a single server.  I'm new to Apache and seem to have written something incorrectly  when setting up virtual hosts.

I own 2 domains that I'm trying to host on a single server.  Call them `www.my_first_domain.com` and `www.my_second_domain.com`.

Now, I have more than 3 Django projects I'm going to be hosting.  One project will be pointed to `www.my_first_domain.com`.  One project will be pointed to `www.my_second_domain.com`.  All other projects will be pointed to subdomains of `www.my_second_domain.com`.

i.e. `project3.my_second_domain.com`, `project4.my_second_domain.com`, etc.

I've managed the DNS to have all these point to the correct IP.  I've verified this with `` `host www.my_first_domain.com ``, `host www.my_second_domain.com`, `host project3.my_second_domain.com`, etc.  They all point to the correct IP.

Below are 3 examples of the files I've setup to try and get this to work.

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project1`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.my_first_domain.com
        ServerAlias *.my_first_domain.com my_first_domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project1

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.my_first_domain.com-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.my_first_domain.com-error.log

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user1/website/project1/project1/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/user1/website/project1/project1>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project2`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.my_second_domain.com
        ServerAlias my_second_domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project2

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.my_second_domain.com-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.my_second_domain.com-error.log

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user2/website/project2/project2/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/user2/website/project2/project2>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project3`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project3.my_second_domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project3

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project3.my_second_domain.com-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project3.my_second_domain.com-error.log

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user3/website/project3/project3/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/user3/website/project3/project3>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to www.my_first_domain.com everything looks correct.  When I go to www.my_second_domain.com I see what is at www.my_first_domain.com (my first project, not my second project).  If I go to project3.my_second_domain.com I get an `Internal Server Error`.

If I look at the error log for project3 it looks like it's trying to load the Django settings for project1.

I purposefully emptied `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` as I was under the impression that the `sites-enabled` files will be used in place of `httpd.conf` when using virtual hosts the way I am.

I don't believe I've modified any other configuration files.  Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: Two comments: 1) you ran `a2ensite` on each of your configurations, correct? 2) Make sure your Python paths are correct in your wsgi.py scripts. Hope that helps. EDIT: Make sure your confs are in `sites-available` and then run `a2ensite` don't just create the files in `sites-enabled`.

Comment: @themanatuf I did use `a2ensite` then edited them to have the virtual host info.  I've also double checked the Python paths in the wsgi.py scripts - `sys.path.append('/home/user3/website/project3')`, etc.  Also, the conf files are also in `sites-available` as they are just symbolic links.

Comment: I don't have access to my server right this second, but I thought the symbolic links were under `sites-enabled` and the raw files were under `sites-available`. I've done exactly what you're asking without any issues, so I'll double check my server when I get home. In the meantime, double check my thoughts on the raw files supposed to be in `sites-available`.

Comment: Yes, you are right that the sites-available are where the raw files are...but if I edit either "file" it will change in both places since sites-enabled are symbolic links.  So, it shouldn't matter.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It does matter, I'd remove the symbolic links and move the raw files under sites-available. Then run `a2ensite`. See my solution below for copies of my conf files as well as my wsgi files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what my conf file looks like:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    Alias /static/ /var/www/domain/static/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/domain/django.wsgi

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain/invite/%1/$1 [QSA,P]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/domain/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's my .wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys 
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/django')
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/django/domain')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'domain.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I have a number of these files and they are all named by the domain name I'm using for the site. Make sure you've got the confs in `sites-available` and you run a2ensite on each one and you should be good to go.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this just isn't working for me.  I see no change.  :(